# Adblock Plus breaks Foundation Orbit

Tags: zurb-foundation, orbit, adblock

I have an Orbit Carousel on my foundation website and when I open the website with Adblock Plus enabled all the Orbit images are 0x0px. 
Other adblock plugins don't cause this and adblock plus doesn't say it's blocking any ads.
How do I fix this?

This is what it looks like:
[image: This is what it should look like]

This is what it looks like with adblock plus enabled.
[image: This is what it looks like with adblock plus enabled]

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with both ad blockers (Adblock and Adblock Plus) while using [Foundation interchange on images](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html#using-interchange-with-images).

```
<img data-interchange="[img/ad-small-375x560.jpg, (small)], [img/ad-medium-1000x250.jpg, (medium)], [img/ad-large-1280x200.jpg, (large)]">
```

Make sure **you are not** using the word "ad" on any of the filename called on your carousel.

Answer (score 0):

Report incorrectly blocked content on easylist forum https://forums.lanik.us/viewforum.php?f=64